# Cannot open Matplotlib figure in new Process on Mac

Tags: macos, matplotlib, tkinter, multiprocessing

If I try to launch a process that creates a matplotlib figure, the process hangs when trying to create the figure.  Here is some code that reproduces the problem:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np

def plotit():
    data = np.cos(np.linspace(0, 10, 100))
    print 'Gets Here'
    plt.figure()
    print 'But This is never printed.'
    plt.plot(data)
    plt.show()

def main():
    p = Process(target=plotit)
    p.start()
    print raw_input('Press Enter when Done>>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output from this is:

```
Press Enter when Done>>Gets Here
```

So it seems to freeze on `plt.figure()`.

**Note: The code seems to run fine on linux - it just fails on Mac!** (My matplotlib backend is TkAgg in both cases).  (Python 2.7.12, matplotlib 2.0.2., OSX Sierra 10.12)

Is there any way around this?

Comment: I can run the above without problem. Maybe you need to give some more details on your system and *how* you run this.

Comment: Huh, ok.  So it works on my Linux computer but not on my mac.  (I run from pycharm, but it works the same from terminal).  I updated the question.

Comment: Well it's definitely matplotlib related.  It hangs on plt.figure().  If I remove matplotlib commands in plotit, it the process will continue just fine.  It's worth adding that it will hang on plt.plot if I comment out plt.figure, not not on plt.show if I comment out plt.plot,

Comment: Also worth noting that the "raw_input" command is not responsible in any way - if I replace it with time.sleep(10) it still hangs on plt.figure()

Comment: Also, commented on github, try running with Agg (or any non-interactive) backend.  I suspect the issue is Tk not liking to create a window on the other side of the `Process` fork, not anything Matplotlib specific.  You can also try just creating a Tk window in the plotit to check this.

Comment: Yes, I confirm that it it does also freeze if I call `Tkinter.Tk()` instead of `plt.figure()`.  And also that it does not freeze when using 'agg' backend for matplotlib (though it doesn't display anything either).  So it seems to be a Tkinter problem.